# Select "corner" elements of a 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I am trying to extract the four corner elements of a NumPy 2D array:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(16).reshape((4, -1))
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

The expected output is either `[[0,3],[12,15]]` or `[0,3,12,15]` (anything goes). True 2D *fancy* indexing delivers only the ends of the main diagonal:

```
data[[0,-1],[0,-1]]
#array([ 0, 15])
```

Pseudo-2D *fancy* indexing (first row-wise, then column-wise) delivers the right answer, but looks awkward:

```
data[[0,-1]][:,[0,-1]]
#array([[ 0,  3],
#       [12, 15]])
```

Is there a way to use true *fancy* indexing, such as `data[XXX,YYY]`, where `XXX` and `YYY` are lists/arrays/slices, to extract all four corners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
data[[0, 0, -1, -1], [0, -1, 0, -1]]
```

Comment: Or `data[[0, 0, -1, -1], [0, -1, -1, 0]]` to go around the corners in clockwise order.

Comment: @damores could you explain this logic?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possibilities. (Ok, first one isn't actually fancy):

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> 
>>> m, n = a.shape
>>> a[::m-1, ::n-1]                                                                                  
array([[0, 2],                                                                                                      
       [6, 8]])                                                                                                     
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> a[np.ix_((0,-1), (0,-1))]                                                   
array([[0, 2],                                                                                                      
       [6, 8]])
```

More explicitly:

```
>>> idx = np.ix_((0,-1), (0,-1))
>>> idx
(array([[ 0],
       [-1]]), array([[ 0, -1]]))
>>> a[idx]
array([[0, 2],
       [6, 8]])
```

The trick is to leverage broadcasting on the indices. `np.ix_` knows the details of how to do it.